# How to add ActionBar to Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I am trying to add ActionBar to my android activity, but app automatically closes due to some code error. So what is the proper code to display ActionBar in the Activity?

I tried this code in onCreate method but its not working

```
ActionBar actionBar;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.timetable);

   actionBar = getActionBar();
   actionBar.setTitle("MY TITLE");
   actionBar.show();
 }
```

Comment: please post the detail error info.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and try to add a bit more information following those guidelines to attract more positive attention to your issue.

Comment: its showing error on actionBar.show();
@JohnnyShieh

Comment: its showing error on actionBar.show(); 
@MeetTitan

Comment: getActionBar() => getSupportActionBar and use a Theme has ActionBar

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

- Don't use the `ActionBar` use `Toolbar`.
- Make your class extent `AppCompatActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`.
- Use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.
- A `Toolbar` is shown by default, so you dont nedd to call the `show()` method.

[Android Toolbar Example](http://javatechig.com/android/android-lollipop-toolbar-example)

Answer (score 0):

Following code:

```
public class Test extends Activity 
         {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = this.getApplicationContext();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // show the action bar title
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        // adding style and colour to title 
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Field");
        s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")), 0, s.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        actionBar.setTitle(s);

    }
```