# How to create title bar in android?

Tags: android

I am new to android and trying to create a title area and title for my app.  what I have is this:
[image]

What I am aiming for is something like this:
[image]

When I look at the XML for each of these the constraint xml is identical. Can some one help me add a title block to #1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Thank you.

Comment: That is a toolbar and can either be declared usign a tag if you have the support library, or just changing to a theme that has an actionbar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the text on the action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/how-to-change-the-text-on-the-action-bar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding ActionBar in Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238416/adding-actionbar-in-android-activity)

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052127/how-to-add-an-actionbar-in-android-studio-for-beginners

Comment: I see what you guys are saying, but in the 2nd example the title is just there by default. Is there anyway I can do this in XML for my initial layout?

Comment: Go to your project `res` folder then `values` then `style` and inside the style folder copy and  paste the contents in your question and then we can see what is going on! And change it from xml. Also adding your manifest file contents is helpful

Comment: @Xenolion as soon as you said that, I looked in the Style and it had NoActionBar. Changed that and it worked a treat. Thank you. If you write that as a solution, I'd happily accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Okay thanks, I am glad it worked It happened to me too when I started Android Development. Thats why I remember that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your AppTheme from `styles` folder from `.NoActionBar` to another parent with `ActionBar` for example `.DarkActionBar`.